# Get merchant email in Square connect v2?

Tags: square-connect

Square Connect v1 has a way to get the merchant email:

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-merchantid

Is there something similar in v2? I can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in the V2 APIs.